# Saving dataframe after text lines in .txt file

Tags: python, pandas, text

I am trying to modify a raw data .txt file to be reprocessed by a software.
Problem is, that software needs additional parameters that are in the text file *before* the data table.
As such, `df.to_csv` overwrites the lines which I need.

The string approach was successful but would not let me use `'\t'` separators

```
#Building example dataframe
index = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
t = pd.Series([2,6,9,8,10,12],index= index)
s = pd.Series([7,2,6,8,5,9],index= index)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time (s)':t,'X Position':x})


file="C:/Users/user/Desktop/example.txt"

f = open(file, "w") 
f.write(f"Multiple\nlines\ngo here\n\n")
f.close()

with open(file, 'a') as f:
    dfAsString = df.to_string(index=False)
    f.write(dfAsString)
    f.close()
```

This gives the following .txt output:

```
Multiple
lines
go here

 Time (s)  X Position
        2           7
        6           2
        9           6
        8           8
       10           5
       12           9
```

I need to add this dataframe to the file but also need the output to be tab separated without affecting the text above.
Help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use to_csv to append new dataframe (tab separated) to an existing file:

```
file="example.txt" 
f = open(file, "w") 
f.write(f"Multiple\nlines\ngo here\n\n")
f.close()
df.to_csv(file, mode='a', index=False, header=True, sep = "\t")
```

The output of this is:

```
Multiple
lines
go here

Time (s)    X Position
2   7
6   2
9   6
8   8
10  5
12  9
```

Comment: The code of this reply allowed me to get the correct output. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a file path, `DataFrame.to_csv()` can take an already-opened file:

```
file="C:/Users/user/Desktop/example.txt"
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(f"Multiple\nlines\ngo here\n\n")
    df.to_csv(f, sep='\t', index=False)
```

Output in `example.txt`:

```
Multiple
lines
go here

Time (s)    X Position
2   7
6   2
9   6
8   8
10  5
12  9
```

Comment: This worked perfectly on the example, but erased the true file's dataframe header and the first 12 rows. A print(str(df)) right before the df.to_csv showed everything was normal.